# Create Solr collection with shared Zookeeper Ensemble

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I set up a SOLR cluster with two nodes and external Zookeper ensemble. This ZK ensemble has 3 nodes. I start my solr instances with parameter:

```
-z zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181/solr5
```

That means, I want the SOLR configuration to be under /solr5 instead of / as it is done by default.

The folder /solr5 is created in ZK with:

```
create /solr5 []
```

I also can upload the SOLR configuration into /solr5 without problem.

My question is when **creating a collection**, how do I get the generated files to be under /solr5?

The command I use to create the collection is:

```
bin/solr create -c collection1 -n configset -s 2 -rf 2
```

I looked at the documentation on [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api1) but i don't see where to specify the zk path. The files and folder generated are:

- security.json
- clusterstate.json
- aliases.json
- live_nodes
- overseer
- overseer_elect
- collections

How do I get these generated under /solr5 instead of /?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to specify the the zookeeper path in solr.xml:

```
 <solrcloud>
    <str name="zkHost">zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181/solr5</str>

 </solrcloud>
```